# How to keep threads untangled when changing vector? c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, thread-safety

This program will crash cause the threads are tangled... One could be pushing while the other is trying to erase.

How can I make this work?

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> v_test;

void push()
{
    v_test.push_back(0);
}

void erase()
{
    if (v_test.size() > 0)
    {
        v_test.erase(v_test.begin());
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread w0(push);
    thread w1(erase);

    while (true) { Sleep(1000); }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Threats don't get "tangled".   The operations they do can be unsequenced.   If you have two threads modifying a single object, then it is necessary to synchronise the operations to avoid concurrent access.   There are various ways of achieving that, such as mutexes (both threads lock the mutex before doing operations and release the mutexs when done -  if one thread has the mutex, other threads are forced to wait until the mutex is released).

Comment: `if one thread has the mutex` got it. Thank you!

Comment: The technical term for what you are calling "tangled threads" is **data race**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to synchronize the threads so they coordinate their access to the vector. For example, by using a [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex), eg:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> v_test;
mutex m_sync;

void push()
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(m_sync);
    v_test.push_back(0);
}

void erase()
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(m_sync);
    if (v_test.size() > 0)
    {
        v_test.erase(v_test.begin());
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread w0(push);
    thread w1(erase);

    while(true) {Sleep(1000);}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate! Does this also work on detached threads?
And is `lock_guard` basically sleeping the function until it is allowed to run (in which case the other is sleeping)? Or is the lock on a flow basis, locking anything after it, and not the whole function?

Comment: Since this is looking kind-of Producer-Consumer-y, [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) could be helpful as well.

Comment: @user19816087 yes, it works on detached threads, and yes, it only sleeps whichever function(s) are trying to get into the lock at that moment.